# The best version of ubuntu ueses for gem5

Tags: gem5

I have question about gem5 .which version of ubuntu is better for gem5?
I install ubuntu 18.04 that is good for running fullsystem mode on gem5 or not?

Comment: Whichever runs your software stack of interest more easily, and ideally LTS. I just prefer Buildroot though.